# C++: Comparing 3 Double values return true when it is obviously false + Crashes at the return statement

Tags: c++, vector, double

So I have this function which suppose to return the area of a triangle using only the 3 points representing it's "corners". In the function I have to check if all the points have the same X or Y values ( Because then it's not a triangle )

This is the function itself:

```
double Triangle::getArea() const 
{
    if (_points[0].getX() == _points[1].getX() == _points[2].getX() || _points[0].getY() == _points[1].getY() == _points[2].getY())
    {
        std::cout << "Error: X values or Y values of all the points are equal";
        _exit(0);
    }
    return 0.5 * (_points[0].getX() * (_points[1].getY() - _points[2].getY()) + _points[1].getX() * (_points[0].getY() - _points[3].getY()) + _points[2].getX() * (_points[0].getY() - _points[1].getY()));
}
```

The triangle is a class, which inherits a vector of the class "Point" which contains all of the points (std::vector ), The class "Point" contains the X and Y value of the point.

The problem occurs when I try to put this Points to the function:

```
Point point1(0, 0);
Point point2(5, 0);
Point point3(0, 6);
```

I also noticed that when I change the 3rd point to be (5, 0) The function don't throws my exception, but then it crashes in the return statement with the error "Vector subscript out of range"

This is the base class of Triangle called "Polygon" which creates the Points vector:

```
#pragma once
#include "Shape.h"
#include "Point.h"
#include <vector>

class Polygon : public Shape
{
protected:
    std::vector<Point> _points;

public:
    Polygon(const std::string& type, const std::string& name) : Shape(name, type)
    {
    }
    virtual ~Polygon()
    {
        std::vector<Point>().swap(_points);
    }

};
```

Sorry for the long question, but this problem stumped me for quite a while. And I'm not very sure why it happens, I've tried and read more about the usage of Vectors, but I don't see something wrong with my function nor with my Vector implementation.

Thanks for everybody who is willing to help! :D

EDIT: The problems have been found, I was being dumb as usual. check the first comments for the solve

Comment: First of all, comparing doubles for equality doesn't work well because they're subject to rounding errors, and then you can get wrong results when it should be equal. Second, you can't do `a == b == c` to see if they're all equal, you have to do `(a == b) && (b == c)`.

Comment: Third, you're accessing ```_points[3]``` in your return statement and that's probably why it crashes.

Comment: Oh you are right, I didn't notice that. Thank you!

Comment: Fourth,  you need to provide representative code.   You describe an expression that is doing operations on (members of) elements of an array, but claim you've fed the function three distinct variables `point1`, `point2`, and `point3`.  Little inconsistencies like that tend to distract people who might help by providing obvious problems that you haven't asked about.